Highcharts Custom Pie Chart Animation Randomly Restarts During Animation
I’m working on a custom animation for a pie chart in Highcharts, where each segment animates sequentially. While the animation works correctly most of the time, occasionally it restarts during the animation process. This happens intermittently—about 20-30% of the time.
Here’s the flow of the issue:

I’ve added custom animation logic by overriding the animate method
for the pie series.
When the issue occurs, I notice that the chart's redraw method is
being triggered during the animation process, causing it to start
over.
If I remove the custom animation logic, the issue does not occur, so
the problem seems to lie in my implementation.

I found this reference: Highcharts Custom Entrance Animation, and adapted the code for my chart. I’ve also set dataLabels to false for the chart.
Has anyone encountered similar behavior with pie chart animations? How can I fix the issue with multiple animations and ensure that the animation not happens multiple times when its already in progress?
Here is the code I’m using:
import { PieSeriesOptions } from 'highcharts';

/**
 * *Initializes a custom animation for pie charts in Highcharts.
 * *This animation sequentially animates the segments of a pie chart.
 * *Starting from the first segment and proceeding to the next until all segments are animated.
 *
 * @param Highchart - The Highcharts library instance.
 */
export function initializePieChartAnimation(Highchart: typeof import('highcharts')) {
    // Extend the pie chart series prototype to include custom animation logic.
    Highchart.Series.types['pie'].prototype.animate = function (isInitialized) {
        // Reference to the current series being animated.
        const series = this;

        // Reference to the chart instance.
        const chart = series.chart;

        // Array of data points (pie slices) in the series.
        const points = series.points;

        // Starting angle of the pie chart in radians.
        const { startAngleRad: startAngleRadious } = series;

        // Retrieve animation options from the series configuration.
        const { animation } = series.options as PieSeriesOptions;

        // Ensure the animation is only triggered once per chart render.
        if (!series.hasStartedAnimation) {
            series.hasStartedAnimation = false;
        }

        /**
         * *Animates an individual pie chart segment.

         * @param point - The pie chart segment to animate.
         * @param startAngleRadious - The starting angle for the animation.
         */
        function animatePieSegment(point: Highcharts.Point, startAngleRadious: number | undefined) {
            // Extract the graphic (visual representation) and shape arguments.
            const { graphic, shapeArgs } = point;

            // Skip animation for points with no graphic, shape arguments, or zero value.
            if (!graphic || !shapeArgs || point.y === 0) {
                // Get the index of the next segment.
                const nextPointIndex = point.index + 1;

                // If there's a next point, animate it recursively.
                if (points[nextPointIndex]) {
                    animatePieSegment(points[nextPointIndex], startAngleRadious);
                }

                // Exit early for invalid points.
                return;
            }

            // Set the initial attributes for the segment (start and end angles are the same initially).
            graphic
                .attr({
                    opacity: 1,
                    end: startAngleRadious,
                    start: startAngleRadious
                })
                .animate(
                    { start: shapeArgs['start'], end: shapeArgs['end'] },
                    {
                        duration:
                            animation?.duration ?? 0 / points.filter((_p) => _p.y !== 0).length
                    },
                    function () {
                        // Callback after the segment's animation completes.

                        // Determine the index of the next segment.
                        const nextPointIndex = point.index + 1;

                        // Start animating the next segment if it exists.
                        if (points[nextPointIndex]) {
                            animatePieSegment(points[nextPointIndex], shapeArgs['end']);
                        }

                        // Determine if this is the last valid (non-zero) segment.
                        const isLastValidPoint =
                            point.index === series.points.length - 1 ||
                            points.slice(nextPointIndex).every((_p) => _p.y === 0);

                        // Finalize animation if the current point is the last valid one.
                        if (isLastValidPoint) finalizeAnimation();
                    }
                );
        }

        /**
         * *Finalizes the animation by applying final updates to the chart and series.
         */
        function finalizeAnimation() {
            // Ensure all points are fully visible after animation.
            points.forEach((point) => (point.opacity = 1));

            // Disable mouse tracking temporarily to improve performance.
            series.update({ type: 'pie', enableMouseTracking: false }, false);

            // Check if any segments have zero values (empty slices).
            const hasEmptySlices = points.some((_p) => _p.y === 0);

            // Update chart properties such as inner size (for donut effect) and border radius (if no empty slices exist).
            chart.update({
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        innerSize: '80%',
                        ...(!hasEmptySlices && { borderRadius: 8 })
                    }
                }
            });

            // Reset the animation flag to allow reanimation if needed.
            series.hasStartedAnimation = false;
        }

        // On chart initialization, hide all segments by setting their opacity to 0.
        if (isInitialized) {
            points.forEach((point) => (point.opacity = 0));
        } else {
            // If not initialized, start the animation process from the first segment.
            if (!series.hasStartedAnimation) {
                // Mark that animation has started.
                series.hasStartedAnimation = true;

                // Begin animation with the first segment.
                animatePieSegment(points[0], startAngleRadious);
            }
        }
    };
}



Could you please reproduce this issue in an online editor I could work on? You can use this basic demo as a template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0pbeym97/ For now I can say that it looks like the custom animation is restarting due to the redraw method so we need to ensure that this method is not triggered during the animation, I'd start with checking if hasStartedAnimation flag works correct.

@DominikChudy, please check this stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-p2dqcs?file=src%2Fmain.js
Do some changes in the values of data objects, its not happening always. once or twice in 10 times. also try to change the value of animationDuration from 1000 to any other value, the animation falls into infinite loop.

Thanks for the demo, when we change the animationDuration to 500 indeed there's an infinite loop animation, however it's strange that in your case it happens from time to time. Does it happen on your machine locally?

Yes, that is correct. That is why it's more difficult to debug why it's happening

@DominikChudy, Hi, is there any update on this?
